# Dúvida - SQL Server 2012 Consulta

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Galera, na consulta abaixo to querendo colocar uma condição dentro do where que traga somente as tarefas que tiverem com vencimento dois meses posteriores a data de abertura. Por exemplo.A tarefa 11111 foi aberta no dia 01-11-2017 e tem o vencimento pro dia 01-01-2018, sendo assim, é para retornar essa tarefa na consulta.

```
SELECT
  tarefaid,
  dataabertura,
  datavencimento
FROM Tarefa t
LEFT JOIN Usuario ur
  ON ur.UsuID = t.UsuIDResponsavel
LEFT JOIN Usuario uc
  ON uc.UsuID = t.UsuIDCliente
WHERE t.TarTipID IN (727, 1053)
AND t.TarNumAtiv = 0
AND t.TarStatus <> 9
AND t.TarEstagioID IN (240, 461)
AND ur.UsuIDGrupo = 30
AND uc.UsuTipo = 'C'
AND uc.EmpLiberada = 1
AND MONTH(t.tarvencimento) = 01
```

Comment: A tabela Tarefa já possui a data de vencimento correto ?

Comment: sim, todas as tarefas já existem uma data de vencimento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma Possível forma, caso a comparação fosse a data corrente, poderia utilizar o seguinte:

```
SELECT
  tarefaid,
  dataabertura,
  datavencimento
FROM Tarefa t
LEFT JOIN Usuario ur
  ON ur.UsuID = t.UsuIDResponsavel
LEFT JOIN Usuario uc
  ON uc.UsuID = t.UsuIDCliente
WHERE t.TarTipID IN (727, 1053)
AND t.TarNumAtiv = 0
AND t.TarStatus <> 9
AND t.TarEstagioID IN (240, 461)
AND ur.UsuIDGrupo = 30
AND uc.UsuTipo = 'C'
AND uc.EmpLiberada = 1
AND DATEADD(MONTH, 2, t.dataabertura) >= GETDATE();
```

Utilizando os dados de datavencimento, sendo o vencimento igual ou maior que 2 meses:

```
SELECT
  tarefaid,
  dataabertura,
  datavencimento
FROM Tarefa t
LEFT JOIN Usuario ur
  ON ur.UsuID = t.UsuIDResponsavel
LEFT JOIN Usuario uc
  ON uc.UsuID = t.UsuIDCliente
WHERE t.TarTipID IN (727, 1053)
AND t.TarNumAtiv = 0
AND t.TarStatus <> 9
AND t.TarEstagioID IN (240, 461)
AND ur.UsuIDGrupo = 30
AND uc.UsuTipo = 'C'
AND uc.EmpLiberada = 1
AND DATEDIFF(MONTH, t.dataabertura, t.datavencimento) >= 2;
```